# Compare Differences in Files

Tags: java, hadoop, diff

I have an application which finds out the Difference between two folders. It provides a report of all Files which are modified in the NEW FOLDER. The report created is a html report which shows the Diff. As for now i have implemented it in normal java and created a web application in spring framework deployed on a tomcat and it works well.

Now the user base is so large that people started providing folders of the rate 1 GB. My application just dies out on this.  Presently in my core logic, I am taking the file as a string array and then comparing each array elements with the corresponding array element in the second array and have an algorithm to handle additions and deletions.

I wanted to make my application support GB's of data and find the Diff.  I am not sure if its very easily possible in Java.  I have just a basic idea of Hadoop.  Is it really possible using Hadoop ?  . is there a pointer from which i could start building the application up ?

---------Adding more information about the application -----------------

Our product application does contains lot of metadata xml files. Some bugs could potentially corrupt xml files. In those cases temporary fix is to provide clean ups(Correct the corrupted xmls). To Track this clean up activity we have this tool which request the developer who does the cleanup to provide the Old Meta data folder and Cleaned Meta data folder . And we create Review reports out of this which will go to the management cycle for review and approval

Thanks for your help in advance.

B1

Comment: To know if it makes sense in Hadoop would require more specific details about what this application is doing.

Comment: Our product application does contains lot of metadata xml files. Some bugs could potentially corrupt xml files. In those cases temporary fix is to provide clean ups(Correct the corrupted xmls). 

  To Track this clean up activity we have this tool which request the developer who does the cleanup to provide the Old Meta data folder and Cleaned Meta data folder . And we create Review reports out of this which will go to the management cycle for review and approval .
 Let me know if its not clear.